# Problema al filtrar en firebase

Tags: firebase

estoy tratando de filtrar datos de firebase con rango de fechas, el problema es que siempre obtengo nulo (null) en la respuesta

```js
var fechaFiltroIn = "1537107647902";
var fechaFiltroFin = "1537307647902";

var consultaHistorias = base.ref("historias").orderByChild("fecha").startAt(fechaFiltroIn ).endAt(fechaFiltroFin);
 consultaHistorias.on('value', function (snap){
  console.log(snap.val());
  

 });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podria ser que el rango de fechas esta muy por encima de los valores que estan guardados en Firebase. Por ejemplo 1537107647902 > 153710764790, entonces nunca va a encontrar nada en ese rango.

Comment: Gracias Javier, pero en la imagen no se ve el campo completo debido a que firebase lo oculta el valor guardado en la base es: 1537207647902

Comment: Si el campo `fecha` en Firebase es un número deberías guardar la fecha de inicio y fin como números, no como texto. Es posible que sea eso. Por ejemplo `var fechaFiltroIn = 1537107647902`

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, 
El problema es que la consulta estaba mal echa, el campo "fecha" al que hacía referencia en la consulta estaba dentro de una "hija" de otra "hija" de "historias" entonces para la consulta el campo fecha no existía en la primera hija (orderByChild("fecha") ) por lo tanto el resultado siempre era (null) 
Cambie la estructura de la base de datos y ya funciona normalmente.   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]